# Connecting GraphAPI - No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials

Tags: c#, microsoft-graph-api

I have this code that trying to access my mail via GraphAPI:

```
public static async Task GetMsg()
        {
            string clientId = "clientId";
            string clientSecret = "clientSecret";
            string tenantId = "tenantId";
            string username = "username";
            string password = "password";

            string accessTokenUrl = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/token";

            HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

            string body = "grant_type=password&client_id=" + clientId + "&client_secret=" + clientSecret +
                          "&username=" + username + "&password=" + password + "&tenant_id=" + tenantId + "&resource=https://graph.microsoft.com";

            HttpResponseMessage response =
                client.PostAsync(accessTokenUrl, new ByteArrayContent(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(body))).Result;

            if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
            {
                string accessToken = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);

                string messagesUrl = "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/messages";

                response = client.GetAsync(messagesUrl).Result;

                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                {
                    string json = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    var messages = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Message>>(json);

                    foreach (var message in messages)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(message.Subject);
                    }
                }
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine(response.StatusCode);
                string content = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                Console.WriteLine(content);
            }
        }


        public static async Task Main()
        {

            await GetMsg();
        }

        public class Message
        {
            public string Subject { get; set; }
        }
    }
}
```

I always get the error: "No tenant-identifying information found in either the request or implied by any provided credentials" although the tenant and all the details are correct.
Anyone have any idea?

I have delegated access to my app. I tried another authentication processes but I understood that I have to do 2 authentication processes: one for the user and one for the app.

Comment: I would suggest to use Graph SDK. https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet. Not sure which auth flow are you trying to follow.

Comment: I'm using delegated access, that's what demand two authentication processes: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/delegated-access-primer
The first is Client app authorization and the second User authorization

Comment: This error might be caused by if you have specified the correct tenant ID in your request.Make sure that you have provided the correct credentials for the tenant.
If you are using a client application, ensure that it is registered in the correct tenant.

Comment: I provided the right credentials. The problem was that the permission: "AllowCloudPasswordValidation" wasn't enabled in the tenant. Thanks everyone!